# Java half of JButtons stop working in JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

I'm trying to make a unit conversion program using Jbuttons in a jpanel. So far when I run the program however, the first window pops up, I select "Length". Now, it shows 8 buttons on each side, after selecting one of those, half of the buttons will no longer work, only the right column of each side works.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

private JButton Subject[] = new JButton[8];
private String SubjNames[] = {"Length", "Mass", "Currency", "Temperature", "Time", "Speed", "Data", "Cooking"};
private JButton Length1[] = new JButton[8];
private JButton Length2[] = new JButton[8];
private String LengNames[] = {"inches", "feet", "yards", "miles", "millimeters", "centimeters", "meters", "kilometers"};
private JTextField convertedFrom;
private JTextField amountFrom;
private JTextField convertedTo;
private JTextField amountTo;
private String from;
private String CTo;
private String ATo;
private int SubjectLocX = 40;
private int SubjectLocY = 50;
private int Length1LocX = 40;
private int Length1LocY = 150;
private int Length2LocX = 330;
private int Length2LocY = 150;
private int t = 0;

public Gui (){

    super("Converter");
    setLayout(null);

    System.out.println("yes");

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    Subject[i] = new JButton(SubjNames[i]);
    Subject[i].setLocation(SubjectLocX,SubjectLocY);
    Subject[i].setSize(200,50);
    add(Subject[i]);
    if (i < 3) {
        SubjectLocX = 40;
        SubjectLocY += 100;
    } else if (i == 3) {
        SubjectLocX = 330;
        SubjectLocY = 50;
    } else if (i > 3) {
        SubjectLocY += 100;
        }
    }

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    Subject[i].addActionListener(handler);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    Length1[i] = new JButton(SubjNames[i]);
    Length2[i] = new JButton(SubjNames[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        Length1[i].addActionListener(handler);
        Length2[i].addActionListener(handler);
        }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600,500);
    setLocation(400,200);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void Step2() {

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        remove(Subject[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        remove(Length1[i]);
        remove(Length2[i]);
    }

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

    convertedFrom = new JTextField(from, 20);
    convertedFrom.setEditable(false);
    convertedFrom.setLocation(40,50);
    convertedFrom.setSize(200,30);
    add(convertedFrom);
    convertedTo = new JTextField(CTo, 20);
    convertedTo.setEditable(false);
    convertedTo.setLocation(330,50);
    convertedTo.setSize(200,30);
    add(convertedTo);
    amountFrom = new JTextField("amount", 20);
    amountFrom.setLocation(40,100);
    amountFrom.setSize(200,30);
    add(amountFrom);
    amountTo = new JTextField(ATo, 20);
    amountTo.setEditable(false);
    amountTo.setLocation(330,100);
    amountTo.setSize(200,30);
    add(amountTo);

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        Length1[i].setLocation(Length1LocX, Length1LocY);
        Length1[i].setSize(90, 50);
        add(Length1[i]);
        if (i < 3) {
            Length1LocX = 40;
            Length1LocY += 100;
        } else if (i == 3) {
            Length1LocX = 150;
            Length1LocY = 150;
        } else if (i > 3) {
            Length1LocY += 100;
            }
        Length2[i].setLocation(Length2LocX, Length2LocY);
        Length2[i].setSize(90, 50);
        add(Length2[i]);
        if (i < 3) {
            Length2LocX = 330;
            Length2LocY += 100;
        } else if (i == 3) {
            Length2LocX = 440;
            Length2LocY = 150;
        } else if (i > 3) {
            Length2LocY += 100;
            }
    } 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600,600);
    setLocation(400,200);
    setVisible(true);
}
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            if (event.getSource() == Length1[i]) {
                from = event.getActionCommand();
            }
            if (event.getSource() == Length2[i]) {
                CTo = event.getActionCommand();
            }
        }

        Step2();
    }
}
}`
```

(Note: I didn't include imports or main method in code above, but is in real program). The constructor creates the JButtons and actionlisteners. The step2() method is where the Buttons size and location and window is created and recreated. (Length1 and Length2 JButtons are what is messing up here). I don't know why half the buttons stop working after the second time though.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select one of the 16 buttons, method Step2() will be called again and this will relocate your buttons, without resetting your locationvalues. When you reset the locationvariables in the Step2() method, the buttons will work. Like this:

```
step2()
   Length1LocX = 40;
   Length1LocY = 150;
   Length2LocX = 330;
   Length2LocY = 150;
   [rest of method....]
```

But off course you don't want to call step2() every time a button is clicked.....

Comment: Awesome, I didn't even think about having to reset those again. It works now, Thanks alot! :p

Comment: You're welcome, but please check out the answer form @AJNeufeld! He also has a point....

Answer (score 2):

You are creating and adding JTextField UI items, and adding them multiple times at the same location, and never removing them:

- convertedFrom
- amountFrom
- convertedTo
- amountTo

These will be stacked on top or underneath previous ones; the user may add text to the top ones and the program may write to or read from the obscured ones beneath, which will stop the program from functioning as intended.

Comment: I forgot I needed to remove these as well as the buttons every time the method is called. Thanks!